How to upload PCAP file in Arkime on Ubuntu 24.04?
I installed Arkime 5.0 and Elasticsearch cluster on Ubuntu and succesfully started new session on localhost:8005 but I dont know how to upload PCAP file from my local files.
I tried to to run this command : sudo ./arkime-process-pcap.sh 01.pcap and I get this result:
[*] Clearing previous Arkime data...
[*] Capturing new PCAP...
[*] Restarting Arkime Viewer...
[*] Complete - please allow a brief period for data to populate

After that I reload my page but it says that Arkime is empty

I would recommend coming over to the arkime.com slack, since that is where we answer most questions.
I'm not sure what the arkime-process-pcap.sh script is, that isn't a standard part of the Arkime distribution.
Basically you just need to do /opt/arkime/bin/capture -r THEFILENAME
see https://arkime.com/faq#how-do-i-import-existing-pcaps

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
